# @Formula annotation error, "schema does not exist" when using + interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

Hey I created a @Formula query which works well but after adding the line with date_trunc + interval, it doesn't work anymore.

```
@Formula("(SELECT SUM(sj.elapsed_time) " +
            "FROM shift_job sj JOIN shift_service ss ON sj.shift_service_id = ss.id " +
            "WHERE ss.monthly_service_group_service_id = id AND " +
            "ss.status = 'scheduled' AND " +
            "ss.create_time >= date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) AND " +
            "ss.create_time < date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + interval '1 month' " +
            "GROUP BY sj.shift_service_id)")
private Long shiftJobsElapsedTimeThisMonth;
```

I found that the query created says this:

```
AND ss.create_time < date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + monthlyser12_.interval '1 month' GROUP BY sj.shift_service_id) as formula1_13_,
```

seems like it thinks "interval" is a field in my Entity (MonthlyServiceGroupService) and that messes it up, can I somehow escape it or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this and it worked for me.

```
ss.create_time < date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + (1::text || ' month')::interval
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a problem with your framework.  Postgres tends to rely on the `interval` for date arithmetic.  But . . . there is a workaround.  You can create the interval using a function:

```
ss.create_time < date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + make_interval(months => 1)
```

or:

```
ss.create_time < date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + make_interval(0, 1, 0)
```

There are probably other methods within the Spring JPA framework that "turn off" this behavior -- something like running a raw query.  But the above should make intervals safe for the functions you are using.